# GNOME Shell Google Calendar doesn't want to run on startup

Tags: gnome, google-calendar

I installed GNOME Shell Google Calendar according to these instructions: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/google-calendar-gnome-shell-integration.html

I also added gnome-shell-google-calendar.py to the startup applications. However the script doesn't want to run on startup and I have to manually run it each time I restart ubuntu. 
Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script seems to have problems with loading the config.json-file while startup, when auto-started.

I worked around this by simply using the scripts `--account` argument.
Your cmd for 'Startup Applications' would then look like:

`./gnome-shell-google-calendar.py --account=yourname@gmail.com`.

Where yourname@gmail.com has to be set up in your Gnome Shell OnlineAccounts.

http://workofprogress.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/gnome-shell-google-calendar-autostart-workaround/

> #### Update:
>
> [2013-06-20]
>
> I Forgot about this here, but as of [2013-03-08] I consider this a
> solution, since it's a built in feature (--account switch) and it's
> just working fine this way.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put correct directory for **command** at Startup Application?

From the tutorial, the folder will be at /home/**user**/gnome-shell-google-calendar

So in command you should put like this :

> /home/**user**/gnome-shell-google-calendar/gnome-shell-google-calendar.py

Change **user** to your **username**